# EXT JS - on click transfer record to store of popup grid panel

Tags: extjs

This is my popup with tabs.
I need to give a value from record to gridpanel in tab 2 in store to get attributes from server side by category_id. Searched answer in official documentation and didn't find.
Can help me somebody?

```
Ext.define('desk.view.CategoryPopup', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.categorypopup',

    title: 'Change Category',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    bdoyPadding: 10,

    initComponent: function(){
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    title: 'Add / Edit / Delete Category',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'name',
                            fieldLabel: 'Parent Category'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'new',
                            fieldLabel: 'New Category'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'id',
                            fieldLabel: 'Category ID',
                            hidden: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'parent',
                            fieldLabel: 'Parent ID',
                            hidden: true
                        }
                    ],
                    bodyPadding: 10
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    alias: 'widget.categoryattr',
                    title: 'Attributes',
                    height: 350,
                    buttons: [{'text': 'Add attribute', 'action' : 'add-attribute'}],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            name: 'Name',
                            dataIndex: 'name'
                        }
                    ],
                    width: 300,
                    store: Ext.widget('categoryattributes')
                }
            ]
        }];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Update',
                action: 'add'
            },
            {
                text: 'Delete',
                action: 'delete'
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
})

This is function in controller

editCategories: function(grid, record){
        var view = Ext.widget('categorypopup');
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    }
```

Comment: so you want to add the record of the form to the store of the grid on button press?

Comment: No. I have a grid with categories, i want to get attributes from database by category_id in popup window

Comment: can you please be more specific: do you mean the attribute of the categories, do you do you need to fill a store from a database...?

Comment: Yes i want to fill a store with attributes, for example i have category_id = 5 and when i click on it in grid opens popup. In this popup will be another grid panel with attributes where category_id = 5. So i need to give category_id value to store for making ajax query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
editCategories: function(grid, record){
    var view = Ext.widget('categorypopup');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/api/category/'+ record.getId() +'/attributes', //example url insert your webservice
        success: function(response){
            var attributes = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            view.down('grid').getStore().loadData(attributes);
        }
    });
}
```

you will need a store with a model for your grid.